# Kendo Grid Filter using contains operator, starts filtering from the beginning of the name field

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

When I use the filter it only starts filtering from the beginning of the Name field.

If I type "J" then it gets me all the names that begin with J, but if I decide to start off with the letter "D" I get no data being returned, which to me doesn't make sense because the operator I am using is "contains".

How do I get this filter to search from anywhere in the values?

```js
var data = [{
    ID: 1,
    Name: "Alfred Kramps"
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    Name: "Albert Pearson"
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    Name: "John Doe"
  },
  {
    ID: 4,
    Name: "Jane Doe"
  },
  {
    ID: 5,
    Name: "John Bender"
  },
  {
    ID: 6,
    Name: "George Costanza"
  },
  {
    ID: 7,
    Name: "Jerry Seinfeld"
  },
  {
    ID: 8,
    Name: "Cosmo Kramer"
  },
  {
    ID: 9,
    Name: "Elaine Bennis"
  },
  {
    ID: 10,
    Name: "Newman Newman"
  }
];

(function() {
  LoadGrid();
})();

function LoadGrid() {
  //$("#VendorsGridList").empty();
  $("#VendorsGridList").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: data
    },
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          ID: {
            type: "number"
          },
          Name: {
            type: "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "ID",
        title: "ID",
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        field: "Name",
        title: "Name",
        filterable: {
          cell: {
            showOperators: false,
            operator: "contains"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: false,
    selectable: "row",
    filterable: {
      mode: "row"
    },
    height: 300
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="VendorsGridList"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the attribute suggestionOperator to get the suggestion for the column you are filtering. You may check out the [API reference](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.filterable.cell#columnsfilterablecellsuggestionoperator) for more details.

```
filterable: {
                                cell: {
                                    operator: "contains",
                                    suggestionOperator: "contains"
                                }
                            }
```